# Integrate RSA SecurID authentication with a j2ee server?

Tags: java, authentication, cryptography, rsa, securid

I'm looking to integrate a J2EE app running on JBoss with RSA's Access Manager v 8.1 (which provides authentication with SecurID tokens).

What configuration should be done to the RSA's custom login module in order to be thereafter integrated to EAP?

The documentation I've found so far is pretty sparse. RSA's site says there: "
Java Runtime API and Admin API; Web Services Interfaces for runtime and admin" but I haven't found more details.

Any pointers are appreciated.