# RSA SecurID development with java

Tags: java, rsa, securid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integrate RSA SecurID authentication with a j2ee server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661231/integrate-rsa-securid-authentication-with-a-j2ee-server)

I'm trying to develop using jsp and java. Is there any java support for implementing RSA SecurID Authentication?

Comment: http://www.emc.com/security/rsa-securid/rsa-securid-authentication-agents.htm#!offerings

Comment: the question ：[Integrate RSA SecurID authentication with a j2ee server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661231/integrate-rsa-securid-authentication-with-a-j2ee-server) is no answer and is closed.

Comment: Since RSA Securid is a commercial closed source hardware product you should ask the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://www.emc.com/security/rsa-securid/rsa-authentication-agents/sun-java-5-3.htm) what you're looking for?

Comment: HI GreyBeardedGeek. 
The WEB AGENT 5.3 FOR SUN JAVA, 
I cant download, this paga has some error.

Comment: In addition, can provide usage or development of documents?

Comment: There's a 'support' link on that page...

Comment: http://www.emc.com/security/rsa-securid/rsa-authentication-agents/sun-java-5-3.htm